# Main content being displayed over sidebar

Tags: templates, css, styling

In Joomla 3, template Yootheme - Eat, the content of tables is being displayed over the sidebar on the right.

For example: [This Page](https://www.portal-gestao.com/item/7015-lista-de-f%C3%B3rmulas-excel-convers%C3%A3o-ingl%C3%AAs-portugu%C3%AAs.html)

How can I fix this?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: It looks normal, may be you have fixed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed Chrome being a bit annoying when it comes to tables sometimes. Others have had the same issue as you.

Add the following to your CSS file which will fix the problem

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    word-wrap: break-word !important;
}
```